# VR Arms in Unity can't be seen through main camera

Tags: unity, camera, virtual-reality

I am making my first VR game and when I put my arms out in front of me, the forearms and hands do not show or render. They can be seen through the in-game mirror that I have but not through the main camera or eyes. How do I fix this?

I'm using the Unity engine. The player model is imported into the Normcore Realtime VR Player prefab and the VR player goes underneath my player rig in the hierarchy. The camera is setup with its basic settings. I have tried adjusting the far and near values of the clipping planes and neither of those work

Comment: To improve your question, click the "Edit" link - do not delete and re-post the question. As I mentioned previously, we need your question to document all the steps needed to reproduce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. We don't just need to know the player model is "in a prefab" - we need to know every button click needed to reproduce that exact prefab in a new, empty project.